# Browse for file to use in packaged Chrome Web App

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, chrome-web-store

How do I access a file chosen by the user from the filesystem in a (packaged) Chrome Web App?

I am writing an image manipulator app, and need to draw the contents of a selected file in a `<canvas>` element.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access [Chrome's file system APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_storage.html), you first need to add permissions in the manifest. Just add **"fileSystem"** (with the quotes) to the permissions list.

To select the file, you can use drag-n-drop (read in the link above) or the supercommon file chooser (with an `<input type="file">`).

Also, you can load an image into a canvas with **[canvas.drawImage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage)**. Is that simple, just set the image path, type x and y coordinates of the image and you're ready to go!

P. S.: Sorry by answering too late! I've just seen the post... :/